# Change to font to italic without modifying the HTML

Tags: html, css

Having this div:

```
<div style="font-family: times">
      <p>my text</p>
      <p>your text</p>
</div>
```

How can the font of the div be changed to italic? I tried to add `font-style: italic;` inside style but didn't work. Like this:

```
<div style="font-family: times font-style: italic">
      <p>my text</p>
      <p>your text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `font-family: times font-style: italic` **is invalid CSS**. Rules (except the last rule in a set) **must end with `;`**. Aside from that, you're expecting `font-family` to be an inherited property, did you check if that is true?

Comment: I meant `font-style`, obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't add a `;` to the end of your first styles statement

Change

```
<div style="font-family: times font-style: italic">
```

To

```
<div style="font-family: times; font-style: italic">
```

---

Example:

```html
<div style="font-family: times; font-style: italic">
  <p>my text</p>
  <p>your text</p>
</div>
```